# JQuery: remove a toggling class from one div before adding to other

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 button like links, which toggle the class "active" for their respective 'arrowbox' divs. here is the html for that:

```
    <span class="ct"><a class="fa fa-shopping-cart"><sup id="itm_count">31</sup></a></span>
<div class="cart">
    hello world
</div>
<span class="ai"><a class="fa fa-plus"></a></span>
<div class="arrow_box">
    <a style="margin-top: 5px;" onclick="new_dis()">Add distributor</a>
</div>
```

both the arrow-box and cart divs have display property set to none, but when I click the buttons 'ct' or 'ai' they appear on screen with following jquery:

```
$(".ai").click(function () {
        $(".arrow_box").toggleClass("active");
        $(".cart").RemoveClass("active");
    });
    $(".ct").click(function () {
        $(".cart").toggleClass("active");
        $(".arrow_box").RemoveClass("active");
    });
```

the problem here is when one div is active ('cart' or 'arrow_box') and I click on the other button, the previous active div should not display on the screen, but it is.. how do I solve it?

also here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sameermanek/fekosyst/) to better understand the problem

thanks

Comment: Its `removeClass()` not `RemoveClass()`, https://jsfiddle.net/7ph647k3/ __Closing question as typo__

Comment: thanks for the help, it works! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is correct but there is a little problem you wrote RemoveClass but the actual function is removeClass. **here is the example :-**

```
$(".cart").removeClass("active");
$(".arrow_box").removeClass("active");
```

Comment: No value addition. Should close question as __typo__